# Should I use entity names in page titles?

Tags: usability, navigation, page-title

**Should I put entity name in page title when editing?**

For example, when I edit an event, should the page title include event name (Edit Faculty Meeting), or should it be general  (Edit event) for all events?

**Example 1**

[image]

**Example 2**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If the events page has a list of multiple events such as:

- Faculty
- Students
- University 
  etc....

I will suggest you use the first examples as **it gives clear visibility of the event you are editing** at the moment. In case even if you remove the text from title field; do some another task; come back to the browser and **the breadcrumb description will tell you what event you were editing before you left** to do another task.

It will adhere to one to the [10 Heuristics](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/):

> **Recognition rather than recall**
>
> Minimize the user's memory load by
>   making objects, actions, and options visible. The user should not have
>   to remember information from one part of the dialogue to another.
>   Instructions for use of the system should be visible or easily
>   retrievable whenever appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The latter. Users need to know where they are within your application. Edit event will stay the same no matter what they are editing, meaning less effort spent on orientating on this page each time it's accessed. You'll see this behaviour in calendar apps for example.

Comment: and you could default the title to some intelligent value if you like

Comment: @colmcq what do you mean?

Comment: I just meant that you can default the value in the title field to Faculty Meeting so the user doesn't have to type it in. They can edit of course